# What's the difference between "the cherry on the cake" and "the icing on the cake"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is there a situation where one would be better than the other? Or are the two phrases used interchangeably?

Comment: [*cherry on the cake* is much less common than either *icing on the cake* or *cherry on top*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cherry+on+top%2Cicing+on+the+cake%2Ccherry+on+the+cake&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)  Are you sure you are not mixing up the two idioms?

Answer (score 4):

"The cherry on the top", is, I think, the more common idiom.  The meaning is pretty much the same:  An inessential element that nevertheless completes and perfects something that is already good.

Both are rather clichéd.